# How do I get Jenkins to build all tags?

Tags: git, jenkins, tags

I want my jenkins builds to build ALL tags.  Even when I push multiple tags at once, I want jenkins to build it.  I followed these 2 links

http://erics-notes.blogspot.ca/2013/05/jenkins-build-latest-git-tag.html

and

[Is it possible for Jenkins to automatically detect and build newly created tags in a git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805603/is-it-possible-for-jenkins-to-automatically-detect-and-build-newly-created-tags)

However my build always just builds my latest tag commit.  Even when I create a new build that's all it does.  Here's the console output for a new project I created - it finds all my branches and tags, however only ever builds the last tag:

```
     > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@<giturl>.git +refs/tags/test/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/test/*
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen branch in repository origin/nraomd
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/test/1
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/test/2
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/test/3
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/test/4
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/test/5
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/test/6
Seen branch in repository origin/tagtest
Seen 11 remote branches
Checking out Revision 5c79568e8a4ff29b48acf0d53548be79daf4ddc2 (origin/tags/test/6)
```

Here's my  jenkins options:

```
Refspec: +refs/tags/test/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/test/*
Branch specifier: */tags/test/*
Poll SCM: * * * * *
```

When I tag I use:

```
git tag -a test/2 a061791 -m 'test2'
git tag -a test/3 8f2c8ec -m 'test3'
git push --tags
```

I've tried */**.  I've had some luck using

```
*/*
```

as it built both my master and nraomd branch, but not my tagtest branch for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: isn't your refspec going to exclude tagtest, it doesn't match tags/test/*, correct?

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I put there while I was testing, perhaps, but my main problem is not being able to build all tags

Comment: I understand the problem, what I don't understand is the problem.  You might want to take the rigspec out and see what happens, because right now that's an eye-opener