# jenkins build every tag on push

Tags: github, jenkins

I want jenkins to build every github tag on push. I followed these posts

[jenkins trigger build if new tag is released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742847/jenkins-trigger-build-if-new-tag-is-released)
[Jenkins Git Plugin: How to build specific tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195900/jenkins-git-plugin-how-to-build-specific-tag)
[Is it possible for Jenkins to automatically detect and build newly created tags in a git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805603/is-it-possible-for-jenkins-to-automatically-detect-and-build-newly-created-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1)

When I push a tag, it triggers a build but with the wrong commit ID. It uses the latest revision (not even master). Is there a way to select the right commit associated with the tag?

```
refspecs: +refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*  

branch: */tags/*
```

also "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" is selected